# selectOneMenu primefaces não envia valor para Bean

Tags: primefaces

Olá Pessoal quero solicitar um auxilio no recurso de combobox do primefaces, em que montei conforme abaixo mas não funciona, testei de várias formas baseando nos foruns da net usando por exemplo valueChangeListener (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848203/jsf-fajax-listener-not-called?rq=1) e não funcionou.

Meu xhtml

```
value="#{ msg['configuracao.mensagem.opcoes'] } "
for="idOpcoes" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="idOpcoes"
    value="#{teste}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{ msg['selecione.um'] }" 
                      noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Opcao 1" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Opcao 2" itemValue="2" />
    <p:ajax update=":formPrincipal:grid" 
        listener="#{meuBBean.changePanel}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Meu Bean
    // var para pegar o valor do SelectItem
    @Getter @Setter
    private Object value = "";

```
public void changePanel(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

            // Testando para ver qual valor chega pelo event
    System.out.println("\n\n\n Valor q chegou event" +event.getSource());

            // Testando para ver qual valor chega pela var value
    System.out.println("\n\n\n Valor q chegou String" +value.toString() );

    if (event.getSource().equals("1")) {
        habilitaPanelGrig = true;
    }
    else if (event.getSource().equals("2"))
        habilitaPanelGrig = false;
    }
}
```

E retorna isso

Valor q chegou String
[04/11/19 23:25:22:041 BRST] 0000012e SystemOut     O 
[04/11/19 23:25:24:645 BRST] 0000012c SystemOut     O

Valor q chegou eventorg.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@a42092ff
[04/11/19 23:25:24:645 BRST] 0000012c SystemOut     O

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver aqui, a questão era o valor declarado no value do selectOneMenu no meu caso de nome "teste" que eu não havia declarado no Bean:

Correção

-- myBean
@Getters @Setters
private String teste;

value="#{ msg['configuracao.mensagem.opcoes'] } "
for="idOpcoes" />